# In HTTP user agent header of Android, what does the "U" mean?

Tags: android, user-agent

I'm trying to implement a HTTP user agent header parser.

I'm curious to know the meaning of "U" in HTTP user agent header of Android.

This is a sample HTTP user agent header of Android:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; **U**; Android 4.0.2; ko-kr; Galaxy Nexus Build/ICL53F) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30

Does anyone know about it?

Comment: even I never think about this ..........+1....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

U for strong security..................

http://www.useragentstring.com/Android%20Webkit%20Browser_id_18032.php

Security values:

- N for no security
- U for strong security
- I for weak security

Comment: Thanks! The site looks nice :-)

Comment: What exactly is 'strong security' vs 'weak security'? Does it have to do with the connection, or the environment that the agent is running in?

Comment: @mailmindlin I came to this page looking for an answer to that same question. Further googling suggests that it is a function of the strength of the SSL encryption that the browser supports.  

Per http://cat-in-136.github.io/2010/08/u-in-ua-string-and-aboutconfig-pref.html (which is the closest I could find to a definition) "strong security" means  "the browser provides crypto support that is stronger than what the 'international' builds of Netscape offered circa 1995", which is itself undefined, but I think you can assume modern clients that support HTTPS can claim `U`.