# In the context of user agents, what do U, I, and N mean?

Tags: security, google-chrome, firefox, browser, user-agent

I've seen a similar question asked here on stack overflow. The answer given referenced [this site](http://www.useragentstring.com/Firefox11.0_id_19276.php) (I have already loaded an example user-agent into it) which says they are "security values". However, it gives no further description of what they signify. What kind of "security" does this refer to, and how does it affect things?

Comment: Why the downvote? The [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847390/in-http-user-agent-header-of-android-what-does-the-u-mean) didn't go beyond what I put in the post above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It describes the level of SSL support in the browser. "Strong security" is "Better than Netscape International was in 1995". Firefox stopped including that information in the user agent string at version 4, so it really isn't worth worrying about.

Comment: So it's something along the lines of "no SSL" "only Export/56-bit" and "strong 128/256"? Interesting, thank you!